# Squid Delay Pool - restricting bandwidth per user / ip address

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, limit, bandwidth, squid

I need to limit the bandwidth of all users on a transparent squid proxy so that nobody is using more than 1Mbps (i.e. at least 100 people can use our 100Mbps connection without one person dominating and reducing performance for everybody). I'm not fussed if the restriction is done per user or per IP, but would be open to suggestions / help on the impacts of both choices.

So far I've added to my squid.conf:

```
delay_pools 1
delay_class 1 2
delay_access 1 allow  all
delay_parameters 4 32000/32000 8000/8000 600/64000 125000/125000
```

but when I run a Speed Test on beta.speedtest.net trough the proxy I'm getting upload and download speeds far in excess of 1Mbps.

Does anybody know what I'm doing incorrectly with this Squid config? Are the first three bucket values (32000, 8000, 600) going to cause me an issue or limit anything else? It's the fourth one (`user`) that's relevant I think.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It matters how much you overcome that 1Mbps, if it's not much just ignore it, you might send some encrypted packages or some stream of files that will make speed test to fail

Comment: I was getting 10Mbps + (anything from 6Mbps to 30Mbps - the connection speed of the machine I was testing on). The limit was having no obvious effect.